# Change system python to python 3.9 to install meson on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, qemu, docker-desktop, meson-build

I am a total noob when it comes to working with os, so please go easy on me :)

Basically my end goal is "simple", I want to install qemu-7.0 in order to install Docker-desktop.

My os is Linux Mint 19.3
My default python3 is obviously "maxed out" at 3.6

I have already taken care of setting python 3.9 as default in the system
(in fact if I type python --version I get Python 3.9.16), however it seems like when it comes to installing packages it defaults to python 3.6

Like I said, I'm a total noob so I don't even know what kind of commands could be useful.

Something else I will add just in case is the *which python* command:
/usr/bin/python

I'm sorry if I did a poor job at presenting informations, but like I said I don't know where to look.

Hopefully I've made the end goal clear, really to just install docker-desktop, but following the procedure leads abck to the problem of not having qemu > 5.2, and installing qemu gives me the error that mason can't set up because my os python version is 3.6 and it needs 3.7 or above.

Thank you very much for any help and have a nice day :)

Comment: you can download and install the latest version (or your selected verssion) of python here: https://www.python.org/

Comment: I do have python installed. I have python 3.9 up and running, the issue is that somehow when it comes to dowloading it reverts to python3.6. Before I had anaconda and it took care of it for me behind the scenes, but now it "defaults" to python3.6 and I don't know how to change it

Comment: Are you trying to build QEMU from source, or install a package of it? If you're building from source, there is no need for the new Python to be the system Python, because QEMU's configure script lets you pass '--python=/path/to/my/python' to specify which Python executable to use.

Comment: Conversely, if you're trying to install packages, then building your own Python from source is of no help, beacues you need to actually have the system package manager know "the system python package is this version", because other packages which say "I need python X.Y" are really saying "the system python package must be X.Y", and merely overwriting /usr/bin/python with some other binary won't change that.

Comment: I git cloned qemu and followed the instructions painstackingly. I enter the folder, I git submodule init, next I git submodule update --recursive, but when I launch ./configure  I get the error that meson requires python > 3.6  @PeterMaydell

Comment: You don't need to change the path of the configure script. You can use the --python option to tell it what python to use.

Comment: I just did it and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much @PeterMaydell